# How do I move a window to the left corner using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

How do I move a given window to the left corner using AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the `WinMove` function:

```
WinMove, Title of the window, , 0, 0
```

([documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm))